# How can I animate Recycler-View while changing the layout-manager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, gridlayoutmanager, linearlayoutmanager

In my app design I need to change layout manager of recycler-view from linear-horizontal to grid layout manager

I need to make this transition smooth.
Can anyone suggest me how can I make it possible.

Comment: did you find a solution ?

Comment: no, i still didn't find anything @Hala.M

Comment: Did someone tried to use only Grid and set spanCount=1, when you need show as list? Will Grid animate itself in that case?

Answer (score 4):

In order to animate the changing of layout manager you will need to apply a **layout-animation** on the `RecyclerView` and for that you need to follow the steps:

1) **Create an item animation file to animate the appearing of items**

**item_animation.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">

    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="-30%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator" />

    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0"
        android:toAlpha="1"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator" />

    <scale
        android:fromXScale="115%"
        android:fromYScale="115%"
        android:toXScale="100%"
        android:toYScale="100%"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        />

</set>
```

2) Then create an XML in anim folder for **layout animation** and apply it the **item animation** as shown:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layoutAnimation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:animation="@anim/item_animation"
    android:animationOrder="normal"
    android:delay="15%" />
```

3) Now when you will change the Layout Manager(say from Grid to Linear layout) then simply set this animation to the RecyclerView in order animate the appearing of the items of the `RecyclerView`:

```
   private void runLayoutAnimation(final RecyclerView recyclerView) {
            final Context context = recyclerView.getContext();
            final LayoutAnimationController controller =
                    AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(context, R.anim.layout_animation);

            recyclerView.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
            recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            recyclerView.scheduleLayoutAnimation();
}
            // Changing the layout manager followed by applying the animation
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
            runLayoutAnimation(recyclerView);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the Code you sent is working as normal animation.

The Thing i wanted is to animate the recycler view items to their new positions in a smooth manner like shared element transitions.

Comment: Okay will check that and get back to you.

Comment: @PavanVarma, did you ever find a solution for this shared transition effect?